# Display image using FileReader and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I've seen lots of examples of this, but still can't seem to get mine to work.

I have an array of objects that contain information about images.  For example:

```
$scope.images = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "cloud",
      "caller_id": "me@me.me",
      "image_path": "file:///C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg",
      "image_results": 23,
      "image_id": 3243242
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "cloud",
      "caller_id": "me@me.me",
      "image_path": "file:///C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg",
      "image_results": 98,
      "image_id": 3125312
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "cloud",
      "caller_id": "me@me.me",
      "image_path": "file:///C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\DSC_9864.jpg",
      "image_results": 1,
      "image_id": 927192
    }
];
```

I need to be able to display these images in an image gallery.  I have been modeling my gallery off of [this gallery](https://codepen.io/joshadamous/pen/CJmIB), for reference.

I  am trying to display the first image by doing the following in my controller:

```
//Image information
$scope.currentImage = _.first($scope.images);

//Display image
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.image_source = reader.result;
    });
};
reader.readAsDataURL($scope.currentImage.image_path);


$scope.setCurrentImage = function(image){
    $scope.currentImage = image;
}
```

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div ng-controller="jobsSampleImageController">

      <h2>AngularJS Powered Photo Album <small>by Josh Adamous</small> </h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="albumImage">
              <img id="current_image" ng-src="{{image_source}}" alt="{{currentImage.caller_id}}"/>
            </div>
            <h3>{{currentImage.caller_id}}</h3>

          </div><!-- End of Column -->
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <ul class="list">
                <li ng-repeat="image in images" ng-click="setCurrentImage(image)">
                  <img ng-src="{{image_source}}" alt="{{image.caller_id}}"/>
                </li>
              </ul><!-- End of List -->
            </div><!-- End of Wrapper -->
          </div><!-- End of Column -->
        </div><!-- End of Row -->
      </div><!-- End of Album Controller -->
    </div><!-- End of Column -->
  </div><!-- End of Row -->
</div><!-- End of Container -->
```

This causes an error:

> *TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.*

From the examples I've been seeing, I'm not entirely sure when they get the image blob?

Comment: I don't think you can use `file://` type paths in this instance.

Comment: @Claies I get the same result after removing `file:///`

Comment: you misunderstand.  what I meant to say is, the browser can't access images on the computer's local hard drive (`file://` paths), only images on the web (`http://` paths).  in other words, `C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg` isn't accessible in the browser.

Comment: @Claies I  know, but in my case I need to display local files. I was seeing that using FileReader is a potential way to get around this

Comment: @Claies Basing my approach off this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32969097/3435610

Comment: that answer doesn't do the same thing.  that answer requires the user to upload a file, but then displays the file without sending the file to a server.  you are trying to show a file on the user's hard drive without the user expressly uploading it, which isn't allowed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I have an uploader project that allows you to drop images and it displays images as you upload them and to do so it uses `FileReader`.

My code:

```
function handleDrop(event) {
        var length = event.dataTransfer.files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var entry = event.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (entry.isFile) {
                console.log('File Uploaded', entry);
                entry.file(function (myFile) {
                    if (entry.name.indexOf(".ini") < 0) {
                        handleThumbnails(myFile, entry.name, i)//This will handle displaying the images

                    }
                }, errorHandler);
            } else if (entry.isDirectory) {

            }
        }
    };

 function handleThumbnails(f, name, ind) { //Displaying images
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute("id", name + ind);
                img.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
                img.setAttribute("class", "imagePreview");
                img.setAttribute("title", name);
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);

    };
```

You obviously will need to trigger something to receive the images. As I understand you cannot access local files without getting permission. Drag drop will give permission to that directory.